# Why is my if statement not returning the correct value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a program that will be calculating the electrical resistance of a resistor. There are going to be about 5 separate functions. 1st function is to find out if resistor sequence is valid & the 2nd (where I'm having issues) is meant to check the sequence provided and see if the letters of the sequence are all valid.

```
#The parameter is a resistor sequence. Example NKOD.
#Returns TRUE if the length is equal to four & FALSE if its not.

def check_length(sequence):
    """ (str) -> bool

    Return whether the length of the resistor sequence is valid.

    >>> check_length('NKOD')
    True
    >>> check_length('NKO')
    False
    """

    sequence = input("Enter the resistor sequence: ")

    if len(sequence) == 4:
        print("True")
        return True
    else:
        print("False")
        return False

#The parameter is a resistor sequence with a valid length.
#Returns TRUE only if sequence contains uppercase D,K,L,N,O,R,V,W,Y,Z
#Anything else, such as lowercase will return FALSE

def check_colours(sequence):
    """ (str) -> bool

    Return True if and only if the sequence contains the letters 
    D,K,L,N,O,R,V,W,Y,Z.

    >>> check_colours('NKOD')
    True
    >>> check_colours('NKOF')
    False
    """
    if any(x in ["D","K","L","N","O","R","V","W","Y","Z"] for x in 
sequence):
        print("VALID")
        return True
    else:
        print("INVALID")
        return False

#Program
sequence = " "               
check_length(sequence)
check_colours(sequence)
```

Input - NKOD

Output - True, Valid

Comment: i think you mean `all()` instead of `any()`

Comment: in addition to @Chris_Rands comment - your doc string state that `NKOD` should return `True` although `D` is not in valid chars

Comment: @Chris_Rands I have tried all() but it didn't give me the required output

Comment: @buran I've fixed that now, the output remains wrong

Comment: `check_colours(sequence)` is not reading input  as sequence is `" "`

Comment: again, in addition to @Chris_Rands - you need to `print(check_colours(sequence))` in order to see `True` as output. As a general advise, it's better if you don't print anything in the function body. This will allow to shorten the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def check_colours(sequence, valid_colors="DKLNORVWYZ"):
    return all(color in valid_colors for color in sequence)

print(check_colours('NKOD'))
print(check_colours('NKOF'))
```

Output

```
True
False
```

Couple of notes:

1. Better don't print anything in function body. Just return True/False
2. Add valid colors as param to function with default value of all valid colors. This way the function will be more versatile - e.g. you can use it to check just for subset of colors.
3. You may want do `sequence.upper()` if you want to accept also small-caps sequence